# Position of panel in the Map

Tags: google-earth-engine

How to determine the position of a panel in the Map without using options like “top-left” or “ bottom-center” or others.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Providing a minimum working example that creates a panel and places it in a map using the aforementioned options would greatly enhance your question, and provide readers a starting point from which to work on and give an answer.  It would also indicate which language you are using. Currently, it is unknown if you are using the JavaScript API or the Python bindings. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on creating a good question that will attract good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You kind of can't do it directly, but you can specify a margin relative to one of those positions, such as:

```
ui.Button({
    label: label,
    style: {
      position: "top-left",
      margin: "0px 300px"
    }
 });
```